# seperate engines working vs single engine

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, efficient-energy-use

What is more fuel efficient: Two identical cars running at 50mph or one being tied to the other and only the first dragging both at 50mph? Or what requires less fuel: Two cars to start from stop and achieve 50mph or the same cars tied one after the other and only the first dragging them from stop up to 50mph? If you can calculate how much in percentage the difference in fuel consumption would be (if any) it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that easy.  Now one engine is delivering about twice as much torque and was probably not designed for that.   An engine specifically designed to deliver more torque would like be more efficient than the two combined.

Lets look torque alone.  Ignore the tow rope and assume the second is far enough back to not get any draft.  In this case wind resistance is the same - shape, size, and speed of the car is the same.  Rolling resistance would most likely be more in the tow.  Rolling resistance goes up with torque and has a sweet spot.  Years ago motor trend was testing an Audi Quatro and to the test the resistance of the front transfer box they disconnected the drive shaft and got a lower top speed.  Then they switched around and only drove with with rear and again got a lower top speed.  After much analysis they discovered all 4 wheel sharing the torque had the lowest rolling resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on work that I've done in the past, automobiles moving at "normal" highway speeds of 50-60 mph experience total friction forces of approximately 50% wind drag and 50% rolling resistance.  Two identical and separate cars driving at 50 mph could reasonably be expected to get the same gas mileage.  If one of those cars was tied to the rear bumper of the other car, the "pulling" car would use more gas than it did before, but the towed car would experience some amount of "drafting", meaning that its wind resistance would be somewhat lower than before.  Due to this, the two cars tied together would use less gasoline than each car running separately (I would expect 10% - 12% lower total gasoline consumption).  However, police officers would probably not ignore such a mode of transportation.

Comment: Yes, air resistance is one major factor. But what about other factors? What about the engine losses due to heat and friction from having two engines working instead of one?